# Tikz : compare x^3 and 2^x * x from x = 0 to 10

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm far from being an expert in TikZ because I just start using it.

I would like to be able to plot this comparison of equations:

[image: WolframAlpha]

This plot came from the [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=compare%20x%5E3%20and%202%5Ex%20*%20x%20from%20x%20%3D%200%20to%2010), which is a very good website to obtain results, but unfortunately not free to download the displayed result...

I try something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:10]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (9.9,2200.9);
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (10.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,2201.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};

    \draw[color=blue] plot[id=x] function{x*x*x} 
         node[right] {$f(x) =x^3$};

    \draw[color=blue] plot[id=x] function{2^x * x} 
         node[right] {$f(x) = 2^x \times x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I've got issue with the scale, with the display etc... and I have no idea how to fix this :/

Thanks in advance for your help,

Best Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:10,scaled ticks=false,ymax=2000,ymin=2,minor tick num=1,xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f(x)$]
      \addplot+[no marks,thick] {x^3};
      \addlegendentry{$x^3$};
      \addplot+[no marks,thick] {x*(2)^x};
      \addlegendentry{$2^x\,x$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I start to realize that this package is really powerful :) thank a lot !

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail It really is. If you want to plot something, go for `pgfplots` first. :)